Getting 'cannot find value' in Accounts struct for Anchor 0.30
In anchor 0.29 this used to work:
        #[account(
            init,
            payer = buyer,
            space = 5500,
            seeds = [
                TICKET_SEED.as_bytes(),
                &lottery.key().as_ref(),            // Second seed component: Lottery account key as bytes
                &(lottery.last_ticket_id + 1).to_le_bytes(),  // Example fixed value, replace with appropriate value
            ],
            bump,
        )]
        pub ticket: Account<'info, Ticket>,

        #[account(mut)]
        pub buyer: Signer<'info>,

        pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    }'

Now when using Anchor 0.30 I'm getting:
error[E0425]: cannot find value `lottery` in this scope
   --> programs/counter/src/lib.rs:146:19
    |
146 | ...   &(lottery.last_ticket_id + 1).to_le_bytes(),  // Example fixed value, replace with appropriate value
    |         ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

Only allows me to do:
   // Second seed component: Lottery account key as bytes
        &lottery.last_ticket_id.to_le_bytes(), 

without the increment, but I really need it.
Tried to downgrade to 0.29 but at this stage it brings a new wave of headaches if I do so

Can you please accept the answer?

You've found a 0.30.0 bug, so for now there's nothing you can really do about this except for downgrading to 0.29.0. Alternatively, you can work around this by:
In your account definition switch
/// Some constraints here
pub lottery: Account<'info, Lottery>,

to
/// Some constraints here
pub lottery: Option<Account<'info, Lottery>>,

Then, in your seeds, do:

seeds = [
    TICKET_SEED.as_bytes(),
    &lottery.key().as_ref(),
    &lottery.as_ref().map(|l| l.last_ticket_id + 1).unwrap().to_le_bytes(),
]


This isn't very clean (but that was to be expected since we're working around a bug here), but functionally the same. If lottery is Some (which it should always be) this will work just like you expect. If lottery is None (which it should never be) it will blow up because of the unwrap call in your seeds constraint.
Update: An alternative workaround is to set
[features]
resolution = false

inside your Anchor.toml.

Update: This has been resolved in v0.30.1, so just upgrade anchor: https://www.anchor-lang.com/release-notes/0.30.1
